# How to create a 100% declarative model?

Tags: alloy

I am creating a simple model of a network. The network contains nodes. Nodes send and receive data.

Here's one way to model the network: Each node has a "data" field representing the data possessed by the node at time t. Each node also has a "send" field recording the data sent to other nodes at time t.

```
sig Node {
    data: Data -> Time,                   
    send: Data -> Node -> Time   
}
```

In the spectrum between 100% declarative and 100% imperative, I don't think that that signature is at the 100% declarative side. In my first paragraph I said nothing about nodes having data stores, nothing about keeping a record of sent data.

Also, isn't "send" a verb? Isn't that a sign that the model is not as declarative as it could be? Shouldn't declarative models exclusively use nouns?

I want my model to be at the 100% declarative end of the spectrum. To achieve that, I must simply state what "is". Let's do it!

What is is there are nodes:

```
sig Node {}
```

What is is that at any time t, a node has data.

```
sig Node {
    data: Data -> Time
}
```

What is is that the network has wires between nodes.

```
sig Network {
    wire: Node -> Node
}
```

What is is that data d is on a wire between time t and t' ...

Let me stop there. Is the second approach that I sketched out more declarative? Is there an approach that is even more declarative?

How to model a network in a 100% declarative manner?

Comment: IMHO, Alloy models are declarative no matter what, as specifications are not sequentially interpreted. Also, I truly believe that using nouns or verbs as field’s name has truly no impact on whether or not what you write is declarative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to separate the semantic content of the model, which is one issue, from the names used in it. To me, the essence of a declarative model is that it records observations -- which may be about state, or about dynamic things like transitions -- expressed in logic. The alternative, an operational model, is to describe behavior and states by building up sequences of primitive actions. A simple example: modeling an action that picks an element non-deterministically from a set. An operational spec might treat the set as ordered, and then use a loop to walk through the set, at each step tossing a coin, and returning the given element when the toss first comes up heads. This models the intuitive operational description: "go through the elements of the set one at a time, and pick one to return". A declarative spec would simply say that the returned value is an element of the set -- nothing else needs to be said.

Regarding the use of names in your particular model, it seems that a larger issue to me is whether the names convey directly what they mean. So `send` to me is not a very helpful name; a better one would be `sentAt`.